# Cannot instantiate the type PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener

Tags: java, android, eclipse, sdk, android-activity

Now i am trying to do another pop up project with Android 3.0 (API 11) ECLIPSE. 
But i got errors. Cannot instantiate the type PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener MainActivity.java

&

The method getMenuInflater() in the type PopupMenu is not applicable for the arguments (int, Object)    MainActivity.java)
Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

```
package com.example.indicationsss;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.PopupMenu;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

     @Override
     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
          setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
     }

     public void onPopupBtClick (View view) {
          PopupMenu menu = new PopupMenu(this, view);
      menu.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu.getMenu());
      menu.setOnMenuItemClickListener(**new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener**());
     }

     public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
          Toast toast = Toast.makeText (MainActivity.this,
            item.getTitle() + "was pressed",
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
          toast.show();
          return true;
     }
}
```

Comment: Anyone know what's the problem?

Answer (score 3):

In onPopupBtClick (), declare your own popupListener interface like so: `menu.setOnMenuItemClickListener(popupListener );`

and then elsewhere in the activity (but outside of onPopupBtClick() ), implement the interface:

```
private PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener popupListener = new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
                  @Override
                  public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                     // etc., etc., 
                     ....
                  }
    }
```